# JMeter - Error when using __FileToString to set GraphQL request body

Tags: graphql, jmeter

(this is a dummy example with [SWAPI](https://studio.apollographql.com/public/star-wars-swapi/home?variant=current))

I'm trying to set my body based on what is in a file and it fails saying the JSON is invalid. But when I set the request body manually the same content the request works.
In the results tree view I can see that the only difference is that the manual request is "encoded", it has /n instead of visual newlines.

Here's the request that fails (body coming from file):

[image: Request with body coming from file]

[image: Request sent using body from file]

Here's the request that works (body manually set):

[image: Request with body manually set]

[image: Request sent using body manually set]

does anyone know a way to force this "encoding" when retrieving the query string from a file?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened a [bug for Apache](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66122) and they acknowledged this behavior but it doesn't seem like something they'll fix soon.

I came up with a solutions that is close to what [@Dmitri T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t) suggested but without using any Plugins

I've created a JSR223 PreProcessor (Language: Groovy) that will replace the special characters that might break the request's JSON. So far the things that I've seen in GraphQL that might break it are new lines and double quotes.

```
def content = new File(vars.get('fileName')).text;
vars.put('queryContent', content.replaceAll(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/, /\\n/).replaceAll(/"/, /\\"/))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a limitation or bug of the GraphQL HTTP Request sampler, you might want to raise it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In the meantime you can consider manually changing [line breaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_break) to `\n` using [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup), something like:

```
${__strReplace(${__FileToString(${fileName},,)},\r\n,\\n,)}
```

should do the trick for you.

You can install `__strReplace()` funciton as a part of **Custom JMeter Functions** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

More information: [How to Use the Custom JMeter Functions Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-custom-jmeter-functions-plugin)

Comment: I opened this bug for them (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66122) and it doesn't seem something they'll be fixing soon. I've managed to came up with a solution similar to yours but without using any plugins. Thanks for the help